# Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript'. > llvm-rs-cc is missing

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk

I am new to mobile app technology. I am trying to configure my system (in Ubuntu 16.04) for apk installation. After I run the following command in terminal

```
sudo ionic cordova run android
```

I got the following error

```
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript'.
> llvm-rs-cc is missing
```

I searched about it , but I couldn't find an accurate answer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found myself the solution to this problem. Its because of the version difference of **build-tools** inside my sdk folder. Updating to latest build-tools version will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The RenderScript APIs were deprecated. Try this [update here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/migrate?hl=pt-br) or remove some cordova plugin that use it.